# Excel find and replace causing issues with range criteria in formula

Tags: excel, formula, find-replace

Currently I have a workbook that has thousands of formulas in it. When I created the sheet there was an unknown variable that was yet to be decided upon.

So I chose to place `(,"**",)` in the formulas with an aim to return and replace this with the variable once it was known with a mass find and replace.

Here's where the issue is. Now when I try to run the find and replace function (I want to change ,`"**"`, to `"<>"`) it not only changes the `,**,` but all other criteria's for the formulas as well, breaking the formulas.

I've tried finding and replacing variations such as (`,"**",`) but I still have the same issue.

If there isn't a work around I can manually trawl through the thousands of formulas and update them but if I do this I may not see the sun this side of Christmas.
PLEASE HELP!

Comment: THE symbol im trying to replace is shift 8 but every time i type that symbol here it disappears?

Comment: The asterisk character is used in Markdown for italics and bullet lists. You can avoid this behaviour by prefixing it with a backslash: `\*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the `*` character is used as a wildcard character in an Excel formula, it's also a wildcard in the find/replace function.

To search for a literal asterisk in Excel, you can prefix it with a tilde: `~*`

More information: [Using wildcard characters in searches](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-wildcard-characters-in-searches-ef94362e-9999-4350-ad74-4d2371110adb)

Comment: Thank you jsheeran for the support. I stumbled on another solution ahead of your answer. I found that i could expand the find and replace to include some more of the formula so it wouldn't effect other formula criteria. However your solution works much more efficiently.